# Is it (reasonably) possible to decrypt data with ProtectedData.Protect using some other method?

Tags: python, .net, encryption, pycrypto

I have a program that uses the .NET method [ProtectedData.Protect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.protect(v=vs.110).aspx) to encrypt a password using `DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine`. I have the decrypted password. From what it [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873666/which-encryption-algorithm-does-protecteddata-use) the encryption algorithm is TripleDES.

I would like to use Python+Pycrypto to decrypt this password, but I'm not sure what the IV is. Is it reasonably possible to figure out what the IV is and decrypt the PW with Pycrypto?

Comment: the IV should be stored alongside the ciphertext, or otherwise somewhere accessible. Without IV, *nobody* can decrypt it regardless of whether they have the key. Provided the mode of operation requires an IV.

Comment: @delnan, I'm sure Microsoft stores it somewhere arcane.

Comment: But it must be accessible if one knows where to look, and obscurity virtually never stops resourceful attackers.

Comment: Keep in mind the algorithm may be "salted" with additional enthropy (another argument for this method). This essentially gives an additional secret key.